# Mysql: Getting the min and mx of date

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement where I need to fire a query to retrieve the min of from_date and max of to_date. My data is as follows:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id                              | point_id                             |         from_date   | to_date             |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1e159ee9-0856-4ea8-88ab-4c0862f667af | c54c3bea-46e8-4377-bfa0-3a03c7abbafa | 2007-07-31 00:00:00 | 2012-04-08 00:00:00 |
| 1e159ee9-0856-4ea8-88ab-4c0862f667af | c54c3bea-46e8-4377-bfa0-3a03c7abbafa | 2012-04-09 00:00:00 | NULL                |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

However, when I fire the following query:

```
select min(from_date), max(to_date) from some_table where user_id='1e159ee9-0856-4ea8-88ab-4c0862f667af' and point_id ='c54c3bea-46e8-4377-bfa0-3a03c7abbafa' order by from_date;
+------------------------+----------------------+
| min(from_date)         | max(to_date) |
+------------------------+----------------------+
| 2007-07-31 00:00:00    | 2012-04-08 00:00:00  |
+------------------------+----------------------+
```

As you can see I want the to_date as NULL in my result. But Max function will not find me NULL. So what is the alternative that I have so that I get NULL back? Also, the to_date column might not be a NULL. In that case I need the NOT NULL proper date. Can someone please help?

Comment: `0000-00-00 00:00:00` might be a better value for a datetime column than NULL

Comment: Null will never be the max date, i don't understand your problem. You can use a coalesce if you want to replace the null value.

Comment: @Pekka, that is not an option,

Comment: @Jean my problem is that I must get NULL as a to_date if we have a NULL value. So the max function has to be replaced with something that I am not aware of.

Comment: Ok then now i can answer :)

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/625b69/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
  user_id varchar(64),
  point_id varchar(64),
  from_date date,
  to_date date  
  );


  INSERT INTO some_table VALUES
  ('1e159ee9-0856-4ea8-88ab-4c0862f667af', 'c54c3bea-46e8-4377-bfa0-3a03c7abbafa', '2007-07-31 00:00:00', '2012-04-08 00:00:00'),
  ('1e159ee9-0856-4ea8-88ab-4c0862f667af', 'c54c3bea-46e8-4377-bfa0-3a03c7abbafa', '2012-04-09 00:00:00', NULL);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select min(from_date),
 case when MAX(to_date IS NULL) = 0 THEN max(to_date) END AS  max_to_date
from some_table
where user_id='1e159ee9-0856-4ea8-88ab-4c0862f667af' 
  and point_id ='c54c3bea-46e8-4377-bfa0-3a03c7abbafa'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/625b69/3/0)**:

```
|         min(from_date) | max_to_date |
|------------------------|-------------|
| July, 31 2007 00:00:00 |      (null) |
```

Some explanation :

1- (to_date IS NULL) return 1 or 0

2- MAX(to_date IS NULL) will take the null value if it exist

3- MAX(NULL) = NULL, if it wasn't the case you should put a ELSE in your CASE/WHEN

Comment: You can do it in a if -- MAX( if( to_date is null, '9999-12-31 23:59:59,to_date)).

Comment: @Jean, that query still returns me the '2012-04-08 00:00:00' for the to_date column instead of NULL

Comment: I have edited my answer, this one is tested and will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  `der`.`min_from_date` `min(from_date)`,
  IF(`der`.`nulls` > 0, NULL, `der`.`max_to_date`) `max(to_date)`
FROM (
  SELECT
    MIN(`from_date`) `min_from_date`,
    MAX(`to_date`) `max_to_date`,
    SUM(IF(`to_date` IS NULL, 1, 0)) `nulls`
  FROM
    `some_table`
  WHERE
    `user_id` = '1e159ee9-0856-4ea8-88ab-4c0862f667af' AND
    `point_id` = 'c54c3bea-46e8-4377-bfa0-3a03c7abbafa'
  /*ORDER BY
    `from_date`*/
) `der`;
```